# angulars js variable value not update

Tags: angularjs

In the below code I have a variable named `$scope.name`. By default it has value **"Hello 1"**. After 5 seconds I have set `setTimeout` function which updates the value of `$scope.name` to **"Hello 2"**.

The variable shows the change in debug mode. But the new value does not update to **{{name}}**. In other words it just show the old value **"Hello 1"** on the page, not **"Hello 2"** which is required.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
var quizApp = angular.module("quizApp",[]);
quizApp.controller("quizCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.name = "Hello 1";

    function pAHL(){
        $scope.name ="hello 2";
    }
    setTimeout(pAHL, 5000)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `$timeout`.

```
function pAHL(){
    $scope.name ="hello 2";
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

**EDIT**
And a more elegant solution which avoids digest errors is to use $timeout:

```
function pAHL(){
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.name ="hello 2";
    });
}
```

Should do the trick. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asheshambasta/AwTL2/)

Comment: if now `pAHL` gets called from within angular, it will produce digest error. I think `$scope.$apply` should be used rather in the place, where non-angular event occured, that way you can reuse the same function for angular and non-angular code

Comment: @doodeec yeah, what you're saying does make sense. But my solution is based on certain assumptions which hold in this case.

Answer (score 1):

change `setTimeout(pAHL, 5000)` to `$timeout(pAHL, 5000)` and inject `$timeout` into quizCtrl

```
var quizApp = angular.module("quizApp",[]);
quizApp.controller("quizCtrl",function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.name = "Hello 1";

    function pAHL(){
        $scope.name ="hello 2";
    }
    $timeout(pAHL, 5000)
})
```

or the second option is to use `$scope.$apply()`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(pAHL);
}, 5000)
```